# Avoid Jackson xmlMapper being used as default objectMapper with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I had to add this dependency to my pom.xml in order to deserialize xml files in my software.

`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>`

However it seem to now be used as default objectMapper by Spring (4.1.6) and all of the rest response which are not explicitly asked as json are returned as xml.

Seemingly, the AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter takes the wrong road.

I tried to force the use of the default object mapper by adding this to the app-config.xml but it did not change anything:

```
<bean name="jacksonMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonMapper" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I might have to change jackson for xstream because it does not extend objectMapper and thus doesn't work the same way with Spring, but it would be much more work than setting up Spring.

Answer (score 3):

I finally wound up with some sort of solution whereby I had to introduce two relatively gnarly hacks. But given how hardcoded the problem is in Spring this is the only way I could see to deal with this.

On the Spring MVC side of things I had to extend the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` overriding the following method. This simply takes out the message converter:

```java
public void extendMessageConverters (List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> aConverters)
{
   aConverters.removeIf (aConverter -> (aConverter instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter));
}
```

Then to fix the `RestTemplate` I had to add this to one of my configuration classes. It also simply removes the message converter.

```
@Autowired
private List<RestTemplate> restTemplates;

@PostConstruct
public void removeXmlMessageConverter ()
{
   restTemplates.forEach (aRestTemplate -> aRestTemplate.getMessageConverters ().removeIf (aConverter -> (aConverter instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter)));
}
```

I opted for the removal of the unwanted converter rather than specifying a list of hardcoded message converters as that does not lock me in as much for future upgrades.